# str_replace() Not working

Tags: php, str-replace

for the first time I encounter such a problem.
It works;

```
function translate($google) {
$en = array(
    "Mother", "Father"
 );
 $de= array(
    "Mutter", "Vater" 
 );
$s = str_replace($en,$de,$google);
return $s;}
```

But this does not work

```
$en = array(
        "Mother", "Father"
     );
     $de= array(
        "Mutter", "Vater" 
     );
function translate($google, $en, $de) {
    $s = str_replace($en,$de,$google);
    return $s;
}
```

where do i make mistakes?

Last time I'll use it like this;

```
echo translate(fonkfonk(str_replace(array("\n","\r","\t"),array("‌​","",""),file_get_co‌​ntents($cache))));
```

Comment: How are you calling your `translate()` function?

Comment: `echo translate(fonkfonk(str_replace(array("\n","\r","\t"),array("","",""),file_get_contents($cache))));`

Comment: what is the value of `$google`? chheck by printing it out and add that output to your question

Comment: The way of use is different in both cases.In the first example the call would look like `$translation=translate('father');`(or wherever you get that string), while in the second example you would have to provide the translation data arrays to the function and call it like `$translation=translate('father', $en; $de);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not providing the values of `$en` and `$de` to your function when calling it.

```
$en = array("Mother", "Father");
$de = array("Mutter", "Vater");
function translate($google, $en, $de) {
    $s = str_replace($en,$de,$google);
    return $s;
}

echo translate(fonkfonk(.....)); // error because translate() does not know what
                                 // $en and $de are supposed to be
```

You are only providing the result of the `fonkfonk()` function as the first argument (`$google`) and not providing a second and third argument.

What you should do is either provide the values of `$en` and `$de` in your function call, or import them when you define the function:

```
function translate($google, $en, $de) {
    $s = str_replace($en,$de,$google);
    return $s;
}

$en = array("Mother", "Father");
$de = array("Mutter", "Vater");
echo translate(fonkfonk(.....), $en, $de);
```

Or:

```
$en = array("Mother", "Father");
$de = array("Mutter", "Vater");
function translate($google) use ($en, $de) {
    $s = str_replace($en,$de,$google);
    return $s;
}

echo translate(fonkfonk(.....));
```